# Protocol is not being called on viewController

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, uicollectionviewcell, uitableview

Currently we have a protocol that is activated in a "didSelectItemAt indexPath" that is located on a collectionViewCell.  It's done this way in order to have the collectionViewCell embedded in a tableViewCell so it can side scroll. When the collectionViewCell is pressed it's supposed to segue to another view controller. As of right now the viewController the cell is associated with the protocol is never called.  Here is the code:

```
protocol handleKnownForImage {
  func knownForImageTapped(movieID: NSNumber)
}

//On TableViewCell
class KnownForCell : UITableViewCell {
  var imageDelegete: handleKnownForImage?
  var movieID: NSNumber?
}

extension KnownForCell: UICollectionViewDataSource {

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print("Known For Cell Has Been Pressed")

    self.movieID = knownForExtendedArray[indexPath.row].id 
    guard let movieID = movieID else {return}
    imageDelegete?.knownForImageTapped(movieID: movieID)//This gets called
  }
}

//On ViewController
extension PeopleDetailViewController: handleKnownForImage {

  var knownForID: NSNumber?

  func knownForImageTapped(movieID: NSNumber) {//This is never called
    self.knownForID = movieID
    performSegue(withIdentifier: peopleToDetailSegue, sender: self)
  } 
}
```

Comment: Where is the delegate being set? And you probably want the delegate to be a weak property to avoid strong reference cycles.

Comment: Do you get the message printed?  Have you set a breakpoint on the print line and then stepped through?  There are two possible ways that the delegate won't get called after that print; movieID could be nil and the delegate could be nil

Comment: Just realized I forgot to set the delegate to self in the cellForRowAt IndexPath